# Can I split the word "being" with a "-" (hyphen)?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, hyphenation, word-formation

In the following sentence I want to use the word "being". I was told that my use of the word "being" is confusing or unclear. Can I write "being" as "be-ing"? Is that even an acceptable way to write the word?

I am saying the members of nature are being without trying to be.

> He depicts the quiet [being *or* be-ing] of the inhabitants of nature as deliberate living and the busy misdirected life of the working man as without reward or self-actualization.

Comment: Are you trying to contrast *existing* and *living*? If so, then the *be-ing* version is clearer than the *being* version.

Comment: I find the "He depicts ..." sentence very hard to understand with either "being" or "be-ing". Renee: Definitions work better when they don't use the word that they are supposed to be defining. Your question would be clearer if you described what you are trying to say (with the "He depicts ..." sentence) without using "being" or "be" in the description.

Comment: I am saying the members of nature are existing without trying to be more of what they are.  This is part of a paper about Thoreau's philosophy and that is why the whole thought is a bit complicated. As I wrote my descriptive example, I got quite a chuckle.

Comment: 1, yes I am saying, "...the quiet existence of nature as deliberate living..." and so you are saying I can correctly split the word be-ing in this sentence in that case?

Comment: 2, I am saying the members of nature are without trying to be more of or do more to be what they are. This is a sentence out of a paper on Thoreau and that is why it is a bit complicated.

Comment: I answered each question and clarified what I am saying but the responses disappeared. Sorry I can't do more than answer in the comment box. Bed time now.

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't. "Being" means what you want it to without gimmicks. I don't think it's improved by adding in the extra punctuation.

Comment: @Lawrence@Scott I responded to your answers but I can't figure out how to vote on your answer and I need to go to bed as I have school in the morning. I hope we get to continue this conversation. I will leave my computer on and check in the morning. Thank you and I will vote when I can figure it out. nite

Comment: @ReneemyreneeReneemyrenee Welcome to ELU and SE, by the way. [Here's some information about how pings work in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). We distinguish between *answers* and *comments*. The community expects to be able to objectively assess answers, so anything less substantial tends to be put into comments. [Here's more about voting on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-do-i-upvote-or-downvote-comments).

Comment: Also, comments are considered ephemeral, and are sometimes removed without notice. Questions and answers are treated with more dignity. To preserve the clarifications you have made in comments, consider [edit]ing your question. Note that questions are intended for archiving, so multiple layers of UPDATE: or EDIT: aren't recommended. [Have a look at this post for more information.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269993/marking-edits-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: With such nonce-words, you need to explain, for example with an appositive: << He depicts the quiet existing, 'be-ing', of the inhabitants of nature ...>>

Answer (score -1):

> **Being** *noun*
>   2 [in singular] The nature or essence of a person.
>   *‘sometimes one aspect of our being has been developed at the expense of the others’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/being)

The phrase "the quiet [being] of the inhabitants of nature" strongly elicits the definition above. That is, it tends to read as "the quiet essence of ...".

Since the comments suggest that you are distinguishing between *existence* and *living*, and wish to express *existence* in your sentence, the sense you're trying to elicit is slightly different. You're referencing the continuous tense of *be* (coloured in this case as *mere* existence):

> **be** *verb*
>   1 Exist.
>   *‘I think, therefore I am’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be)

You also ask:

> Can I write "being" as "be-ing"? Is that even an acceptable way to write the word?

Consider this from [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=1), a respected writer on grammar:

> Sometimes, the placement of a hyphen changes the meaning of your sentence. Let’s say you want a “hot-water bottle.” With a hyphen between “hot” and “water” you clearly want a water bottle for holding hot water because “hot” and “water” are joined by a hyphen. Without the hyphen between “hot” and “water, you might want a water bottle that is hot. See how the presence or absence of a hyphen could change the meaning?
>   ...
>   The more likelihood there is for confusion, the more you need a hyphen.

[YourDictionary.com](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/hyphen-rules.html) says something similar:

> The fact is, there’s really no set of hyphen rules on which every person can agree.
>   ...
>   Hyphens can be useful to avoid confusion.

From the above, I'd argue that you should use the hyphenated form *be-ing* in your context because it elicits the 'be' sense more strongly than the 'being' sense (with respect to the two definitions cited above). It's a legitimate use of the hyphen (avoiding confusion) because the 'being' sense would otherwise dominate.